# Can Postfix handle multiple address extensions like Qmail does (user-ext1-ext2@example.com)?

Tags: email, postfix, qmail

Qmail and Postfix support address extensions like `username-ext1@example.com` where emails will be delivered to `username`, if the delimiter is configured to `-`.

Users can handle mails with `.forward` files in their home directory by default. (Or `.qmail` for Qmail.)

Emails to `username-ext1@example.com` are handled by the `.forward-ext1` file if it exists, otherwise `.forward` is used as fallback.

For `username-ext1-ext2@example.com` Qmail tries `.qmail-ext1-ext2`, then `.qmail-ext1` and finally `.qmail`.

Postfix tries `.forward-ext1-ext2` and then directly `.forward` without caring about `.forward-ext1`.

**How can I get Postfix to handle multiple address extensions?** I want to catch all mails to `username-ext1-*@example.com` without parsing headers myself in `.forward`. – Did I miss something?

(This would also be useful for users who want to have multiple VERP-style mailing lists with simple separate configurations.)

Answer (score -1):

yes, according to
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter

```
# Handle both Postfix and qmail extensions (Postfix 2.11 and later).
recipient_delimiter = +-
```

HTH

Comment: Neither the link, nor your TLA have any insights on addresses with multiple delimiter characters.

Comment: the main question was about plus and/or dash as delimiter in postfix .. and my answer was yes to that question.
AFAIK only the first delimiter will be be used, that is + OR - !! there is no second sub-sub-extension. that is why username-ext1-ext2 and username+ext1-ext2 are the same if you configure +- as recipient_delimiter.

Comment: You misunderstood the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if postfix can actually handle multiple extensions in a row. at least it is able to use more than one delimiter making it able to handle two extensions (hence to word multiple). therefore I cannot simply answer no the the main question.
whats the point of you answering me rather that Robert? whats the point of trying to use postfix if Qmail does what he wants?
I just tried to give _some_ answer as a starting point for you guys. Hope This Helps